# Not Found 404 NotFoundError: Not Found - Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run the application in terminal (macOS) (DEGUG=app:* npm run devstart), it works fine (server Listening on port 3000 +0ms). However, when I open localhost at browser it simply appears the "Welcome Express" page, and when I go to a specific route, it appears NotFoundError: Not Found.

I have been guided by this structure (on https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html).

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

This is part of my code on one of my Controllers, where I use 404 responses:

```
var CCSelectionCriterion = require('../models/ccselectioncriterion');
var async = require('async');

const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const { sanitizeBody } = require('express-validator/filter');

// Display detail page for a specific CCSelectionCriterion.
exports.ccselectioncriterion_detail = function (req, res, next) {

    CCSelectionCriterion.findById(req.params.id)
        .exec(function (err, ccselectioncriterion) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (ccselectioncriterion==null) { // No results.
                var err = new Error('CC Selection Criterion not found');
                err.status = 404;
                return next(err);
            }
            // Successful, so render.
            res.render('ccselectioncriterion_detail', {title: 'CC Selection Criterion Detail', ccselectioncriterion: ccselectioncriterion});
        })
};
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please try to make a [***Minimal***, Complete and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: Great. I wil take this into account. I have edited my question. Thank you @FZs